# How can I make register_rest_field return for some but not all endpoints?

Tags: wordpress, rest

I would like register_rest_field to return a certain field for a user only when a specific user is being requested (i.e. the request is /user/$user_id) -- not when /users or other endpoints are used.

One way I can think of to sort of do this would be to check the API request URL in the register_rest_field function and conditionally change the return value depending on the endpoint, but I don't know how to access that URL.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use $request->get_url_params(); to check if request has $user_id or not.

Ref:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#arguments

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

add_filter( 'rest_prepare_user', 'mo_user_json', 10, 3);
function mo_user_json( $data, $user, $request ) {
    $response_data = $data->get_data();
    // for remove fields
    unset($response_data['avatar_urls']);
    unset($response_data['url']);
    unset($response_data['description']);
    // array user meta
    $usermetas = [];
    $metas = [
        'field1',
        'field2',
        'field3',
        'field4',
        'field5',
        'field6',
    ];
    foreach ($metas as $meta) {
        if(!empty(get_user_meta( $user->ID, $meta))){
            $info = get_user_meta( $user->ID, $meta);
            $usermetas[$meta] = $info[0];
        }
    }
    // format json
    $nodes = [
        'field1'    => $usermetas['field1']
        'field2'    => $usermetas['field2']
        'field3'    => $usermetas['field3'],
        'field4'    => [
            'field4'    => $usermetas['field4']
            'field5'    => $usermetas['field5']
            'field6'    => $usermetas['field6']
        ]
    ];
    foreach ($nodes as $key => $node) {
        $response_data['meta'][$key] = $node;
    }
    // add fields formated in json
    $data->set_data( $response_data );
    return $data;
}
```